# How to get WSADMIN prompt in Connections 5

Tags: connection, wsadmin

sorry for the noob question but I just cant get the wsadmin prompt to appear in the cmd window.

I have navigated to the Deployment Manager dir and then the bin dir. I type the following

```
D:\IBM\Websphere\AppServer\profiles\Dmgr01\bin>wsadmin -lang jython -username username -password p@ssw0rd
```

but after a pause of a couple of seconds the prompt returns as it was before.

I am expecting

```
wsadmin>
```

There is nothing in the log files unfortunately. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Graeme

Answer (score 0):

I needed to run the cmd prompt as Administrator!

Doh!